# Observe a file in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to observe a Json file in Android but it's not working.
My file is located in the Download directory.

In my Activity I observe my file like this :

```
val jsonConfig = JsonConfigFileObserver(File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), FILE_NAME_CONF).absolutePath) { jsonConfig ->
            runActionFromConfig(jsonConfig)
        }
jsonConfig.startWatching()
```

This is my **JsonConfigFileObserver** class :

```
class JsonConfigFileObserver(private var path: String, var onModify: (JsonConfig) -> Unit) : FileObserver(path, MODIFY) {
    override fun onEvent(event: Int, pathNullable: String?) {
            Log.d("FileObserver: ", "File Modified")
            onModify(jsonConfig(path))
    }
}
```

So I push a new version of my config file using adb :

```
adb push myConfigFile.json ./storage/emulated/0/Download/myConfigFile.json
```

The file is updated but I never enter in the `onEvent` method.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: First guess. it got garbage collected: Warning: If a FileObserver is garbage collected, it will stop sending events. To ensure you keep receiving events, you must keep a reference to the FileObserver instance from some other live object. (from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver)

Comment: Beyond that, make sure that you hold permissions to read that directory, including requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime. And note that this approach will not work on Android Q (by default) or Android R+ (for all apps), as you no longer have filesystem access to this directory.